# C code translated to Qt crashes while executing

Tags: qt, c++11

I´m a beginner on programming and Qt, but as liked the framework I´m trying to improve my skills and write my C++ codes on it. I got a task of writing a Ricker wavelet code and then plot it.
I divided it in two tasks, first make the ricker code works, and when it is running, then implement a way to plot it, I will use qcustomplot for it.
I got a code from C and I´m trying to adapt it to Qt. Although it doesn´t give any errors during compilation, when executing it crashes, with the following message:

> *Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function. C:/Users/Flavio/Documents/qtTest/build-ricker2-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/ricker2.exe
>   exited with code 255*

**The code I´m supposed to translate is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
float *rickerwavelet(float fpeak, float dt, int *nwricker);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    float dt;
    float fpeak;

    float *wricker=NULL;
    int nwricker;

    fpeak = atof(argv[1]);
    dt = atof(argv[2]);

    wricker = rickerwavelet(fpeak, dt, &nwricker);

    /* show value of ricker wavelets */
    for (i=0; i<nwricker; i++)
        printf("%i. %3.5f \n", i, wricker[i]);

    free(wricker);
    return(1);
}

/* ricker wavelet function, return an array ricker wavelets */
float *rickerwavelet(float fpeak, float dt, int *nwricker)
{
    int i, k;
    int nw;
    int nc;
    float pi;
    float nw1, alpha, beta;
    float *wricker=NULL;

    pi = 3.141592653589793;
    nw1 = 2.2/fpeak/dt;
    nw = 2*floor(nw1/2)+1;
    nc = floor(nw/2);

    wricker = (float*) calloc (nw, sizeof(float));
    for (i=0; i<nw; i++)
    {
        k = i+1;
        alpha = (nc-k+1)fpeakdtpi;
        beta = pow(alpha, 2.0);
        wricker[i] = (1 - (beta2)) * exp(-beta);
    }

    (*nwricker) = nw;
    return(wricker);
}
```

**The code i wrote on Qt is:**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <qmath.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int i,k,nw,nc;
    double *wricker=NULL;
    int nwricker = 60;
    int wavelet_freq = 30;
    int polarity=1;
    int sampling_rate=0.004;
    float nw1, alpha, beta;
    const double pi = 3.141592653589793238460;

    nw1 = 2.2/wavelet_freq/sampling_rate;
    nw = 2*floor(nw1/2)+1;
    nc = floor(nw/2);

    wricker = (double*)calloc (nw, sizeof(double));
    for (i=0; i<nw; i++)
    {
        k = i+1;
        alpha = (nc-k+1)wavelet_freqsampling_ratepi;
        beta = pow(alpha, 2.0);
        wricker[i] = polarity((1 - (beta2)) * exp(-beta));
    };
    /* show value of ricker wavelets */
    for (i=0; i<nwricker; i++)
    {
        qDebug()<<i<<wricker[i];
    };

    free(wricker);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Analytic expression

The amplitude A of the Ricker wavelet with peak frequency f at time t is computed like so:

```
A = (1-2 pi^2 f^2* t^2) e^{-pi^2* f^2* t^2}
```

**A py code for it would be:**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ricker(f, length=0.128, dt=0.001):
    t = np.arange(-length/2, (length-dt)/2, dt)
    y = (1.0 - 2.0*(np.pi2)(f2)(t2)) * np.exp(-(np.pi2)(f2)(t**2))
    return t, y

f = 25 # A low wavelength of 25 Hz
t, w = ricker(f)
```

What seems quite simple.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong in my code???

Doing a bit of Debugging I found the problem is when passing the vectors to qDebug, it give a message:

> THE INFERIOR STOPPED BECAUSE IT RECEIVED A SIGNAL FROM THE OPERATING
>   SYSTEM . SIGNAL NAME: SIGSEGV SIGNAL MEANING: SEGMENTATION FAULT

I´ll search for more information on this signal meaning. I used `qDebug` only with the intention of showing the data on a terminal to make sure the calculation was working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: What is `beta2` ... what is  `wavelet_freqsampling_ratepi` ?? How come you declare `polarity` as `int` and use as function in the code ? .. please share [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code

Comment: What do you think the value of `int sampling_rate=0.004;` is?

Comment: And in C++ an array with dynamic size is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Your code seems to be a mix of both. Chose one and then learn how to code for that language with a good book. Don't do C to C++ conversions, or projects that rely on both languages due to library dependencies or whatever, until you are proficient enough to really know what you're doing.

Comment: @MohammadKanan, beta2 is the pi^2*f^2*t^2 term of the equation. When i tried to translate it to Qt, I called f(freq) = wavelet_freq and dt=sampling_rate, pi is the constant=3,14.... I did that because i did an interface where one can select many parameters, some of them being dt and freq that will be the input for this equation in particular.

Comment: @MohammadKanan, the term on the code should be:  alpha = (nc-k+1)*wavelet_freq *sampling_rate *pi; and beta = pow(alpha, 2.0);

Comment: @MohammadKanan polarity is an int (-1 or 1) that multiplies the equation: wricker[i] = polarity*((1 - (beta2)) * exp(-beta)); don´t know why it didn´t paste

Answer (score 2):

C++ is much more like Python than C. Even though your C code was particularly convoluted, it still isn't as nice a C++ can be.

A complete example that even plots the data can be very, very simple. If that doesn't show the combined power of C++ and Qt, I hardly know what will :)

[image: screenshot of the example]

#### wavelet-plot-50690312.pro file

```
QT = charts
SOURCES = main.cpp
```

#### main.cpp

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/wavelet-plot-50690312
#include <QtCharts>
#include <cmath>

const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;

QVector<QPointF> ricker(double f, double length = 2.0, double dt = 0.001) {
   size_t N = (length - dt/2.0)/dt;
   QVector<QPointF> w(N);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      double t = -length/2 + i*dt;
      w[i].setX(t);
      w[i].setY((1.0 - 2*pi*pi*f*f*t*t) * exp(-pi*pi*f*f*t*t));
   }
   return w;
}

QLineSeries *rickerSeries(double f) {
   auto *series = new QLineSeries;
   series->setName(QStringLiteral("Ricker Wavelet for f=%1").arg(f, 2));
   series->replace(ricker(f));
   return series;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QChartView view;
   view.chart()->addSeries(rickerSeries(1.0));
   view.chart()->addSeries(rickerSeries(2.0));
   view.chart()->createDefaultAxes();
   view.setMinimumSize(800, 600);
   view.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Of course, this looks nice in C++. How about C? Let's pretend we had some C binding for Qt. Then it might look as follows:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/wavelet-plot-50690312/c-binding
#include "qc_binding.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;

CQVector *ricker(double f, double length, double dt) {
   scope_enter();
   size_t N = (length - dt/2.0)/dt;
   CQVector *vector = CQVector_size_(CQ_, CQPointF_type(), N);
   CQPointF *const points = CQPointF_(CQVector_data_at(vector, 0));
   for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      double t = -length/2 + i*dt;
      points[i].x = t;
      points[i].y = (1.0 - 2*pi*pi*f*f*t*t) * exp(-pi*pi*f*f*t*t);
   }
   return scope_leave_ptr(vector);
}

CQLineSeries *rickerSeries(double f) {
   scope_enter();
   CQLineSeries *series = CQLineSeries_(CQ_);
   CQLineSeries_setName(series, CQString_asprintf(CQ_, "Ricker Wavelet for f=%.2f", f));
   CQLineSeries_replaceVector(series, ricker(f, 2.0, 0.001));
   return scope_leave_ptr(series);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   scope_enter();
   CQApplication *app = CQApplication_(CQ_, &argc, argv);
   CQChartView *view = CQChartView_(CQ_);
   CQChart *chart = CQChartView_getChart(view);
   CQChart_addLineSeries(chart, rickerSeries(1.0));
   CQChart_addLineSeries(chart, rickerSeries(2.0));
   CQChart_createDefaultAxes(chart);
   CQWidget *view_ = CQWidget_cast(view);
   CQWidget_setMinimumSize(view_, 800, 600);
   CQWidget_show(view_);
   return scope_leave_int(CQApplication_exec(app));
}
```

With a little bit of work, a C binding can be made that is about as easy to use as C++: scopes are tracked, RAII works, destructors get called when needed, values about to be returned are not destructed, etc.

Such a minimum binding, implementing all that's needed to run the code above, is available at https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/wavelet-plot-50690312/c-binding.

Comment: Qt Charts got released with Qt 5.7, so in June 2016. That's two years ago already...

Comment: because of platform and security problem my area got 3.8, 4.6.8, 5.4 as mainstream, newer simply didn't had enough of testing: think of government level of approval (and in general require too much resources for platform and tass we use it), so I wasn't aware of that. If that's 5.7, it's still out of reach for me. In addition, that newer Qt site is ridiculously bad at providing information on changes\additions and is blocking access to some ISPs in country

Comment: You can always port an individual module, Qt Charts doesn't depend on anything else - you can essentially pick up the source files you want, and build on 5.4. Or even 4.6.8 - it'll require minor changes. If you think that the charts provide bang for the buck. But anyway, you're more than welcome to use Qt outside of work's limitations :)

Comment: Just so there are no misunderstandings: **If you're using any new Qt released within the last two years** (not patch of an older version), **you HAVE Qt Charts**. Sometimes you just have to try things first. Qt is easy to use. If you can build stuff with your downloaded Qt install, then you can download my project (source links are all included!), open the `.pro` file in Qt Creator, wait 15 seconds, press Ctrl-R (or Cmd-R), and it should build and start up in a few seconds. I think you might have fallen prey to paralysis by analysis. At least try to get some experimental results to confirm :)

Comment: @KubaOber, Thanks for the replies, I did what u said, and although ur code runs smoothly, it doesnt show any plot, only a gray dialog window. That is strange, because the examples run. I found the QCharts module on their website and downloaded the sourcefile. Dindn´t installed though, now I´m not sure if I have it or not.  Looking at their website, it says the Qt Charts is limited to GPL use only.

Comment: I´m using Qt 5.10.1, I just got it from their website, like two weeks ago. I found some books on the internet as well, seems it is very powerfull for interfaces, lots of information about the widgets, etc.  I just can´t  find much information about C++ development with it. Some commands are very different from C++

Comment: @FlavioMesquita Qt is a C++ framework. There's nothing "different" about it from C++.

Comment: @FlavioMesquita What platform is that? What is your compiler? Please don't mess with downloading anything else. If you didn't have the Qt Charts module available, this wouldn't even compile. I'll see if there's perhaps something mac-specific that I did, but it'd be weird.

Comment: @KubaOber, Thanks anyway, u helped me a lot, I adapted ur code to plot using qwt, it works fine, I did a GUI that takes the parameters such as f, dt and save it in a txt file. Now I´m trying to integrate the GUI with the code to pass the values to the ricker function execute. Is it a thread? I´m reading about it just now, maybe a simple one.

Comment: @KubaOber, I´m using Windows 7, and the compiler is MingW32 built in with Qt. If u look at their website on the download section, the Opensource version only comes with QCharts for GPL use only, there are many topics here on this forum about people complaining that Qcharts module is not available on the opensource Qt.

Comment: You do understand that GPL is very much open source, right? What you're saying is that you want to release a closed-source application, and thus need to use LGPL-only? Then it's quite easy to implement the bits of Qt Charts that you need, but use the full module for experiments and further development. I find it curious that you never used the words "closed-source" and asserted that you need **L**GPL, not merely GPL.

Comment: The `ricker` function is not a thread. Those calculations are trivial, you can of course execute them using `QtConcurrent::run`, but there's perhaps little point to doing so unless you calculate hundreds of thousands of values. It's just a function that gives you the result you need. That's all. Not any different than a function in any programming language, really. It's a pure function, too - it has no state.

Comment: @KubaOber, I figured what was wrong with QtCharts, I just had to add the line : using namespace QtCharts;
 before the code, otherwise it doesnt work.